# Smallest value of fraction

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Does the fraction $\frac{2x-3}{2x+1}$ have a minimum positive value, if so how do you find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is continuous and has a zero ($x=3/2$), therefore it cannot have a minimum positive value. To see this more clearly, choose a number, such as $x_0=2$, so that $f(x_0)=1/5>0$. Then the Intermediate Value Theorem tells us that for every $c\in(0,1/5)$, there exists an $x\in(3/2,2)$ such that $f(x)=c$. Since $(0,1/5)$ has no minimum positive value, $f(x)$ has no minimum positive value.

If you are instead interested in nonnegative values, then $0$ is of course, a minimum.

Comment: Would it be continuous at x = -1/2?

Comment: @fosho no, it isn't.

Comment: $x=-1/2$ isn't in the domain. We would have to define it somehow. If you're asking about one-sided limits, then they do not diverge in the same way, so we would say no.

Comment: @fosho: I clarified the argument of why there is no minimum positive number.

Answer (score 0):

$$(2x-3)/(2x+1)=1 - 4/(2x+1)$$

This is min when $4/(2x+1)$ is max. This is possible when $2x+1$ is min but its a straight line going till negative infinity. Hence no global minima of the function.

Comment: He is asking about minimum positive values, not global minima. Just thought I'd let you know.